# How to print correctly with railway cypher

Tags: python, function, printing

I have some code using something called railway cipher (if you don't know what it is google it). Whenever I enter: Encrypt (2, "This is a test.") I want it to enter: hsi  etTi sats.

However, my code makes it print it in reverse: Ti sats.hsi  et.

Do you know how I can fix it.

***My code:***

```
def Encrypt(numRails, plainText):
    cipherText = ""
    railDict = {}
    rail = 0

    for rail in range(numRails):
        railDict["rail"+str(rail)] = ""
        rail += 1

    for i in range(len(plainText)):
        mod = i%numRails
        railDict["rail" + str(mod)] += plainText[i]

    for i in range(numRails):
        cipherText += railDict["rail" + str(i)]

    print (cipherText)

    return cipherText

Encrypt(2, "This is a test.")
```

Comment: You are talking about a rail **fence** c**i**pher?

Comment: Is this a working code? numRails is used even before assigned any value. Hence my question.

Comment: telling us to go google it isnt going to help you get your question answered ... see [mcve]

Comment: According to Wikipedia, you're supposed to go back and forth through the rails. If you just use `i % numRails`, you're just going in one direction.

Comment: Why use a dictionary instead of a list indexed by `rail`?

Comment: I get the same result as you with my corrected code. Why do you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to go back and forth over the rails when assigning, but you're just going in one direction and then going back to the beginning by using `i % numRails`.

There's no need to use a dictionary for the rails. Just use a list indexed by the rail number.

```
def Encrypt(numRails, plainText):
    rails = [""] * numRails
    rail = 0
    direction = 1

    for c in plainText:
        rails[rail] += c
        rail += direction
        # check if we need to change directions
        if direction == 1 and rail >= numRails:
            direction = -1
            rail = numRails - 2
        elif direction == -1 and rail < 0:
            direction = 1
            rail = 1

    cipherText = "".join(rails)

    print (cipherText)

    return cipherText
```

This gets the same result as the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher) page.